# C# unity Parsing error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im having difficulty with parsing errors on unity 
i have no idea why im getting them this is the bit of code
is where i am getting the error
im following a tutorial and it works for him
skip to 29:32 to see him do it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZosl_-Xf_U

```
void Start() 
    {
        tankBtns[gameManger.instance.playerTankN]
        playerNameInput.text = gameManager.instance.playerName;
    }
```

Comment: Continue watching the tutorial... he adds more

Comment: ok will do thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies solely within the fact the first line is unfinished code.  Simply replace:

```
tankBtns[gameManger.instance.playerTankN]
playerNameInput.text = gameManager.instance.playerName;
```

with:

```
tankBtns[gameManger.instance.playerTankN].onClick.Invoke();
tankBtns[gameManger.instance.playerTankN].Select();
playerNameInput.text = gameManager.instance.playerName;
```

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This error shows due to terminator missing or bracket missing you have missed some incomplete line. Complete that line of code like

```
tankBtns[gameManger.instance.playerTankN].onClick.Invoke();
tankBtns[gameManger.instance.playerTankN].Select();
```

Instead of

> tankBtns[gameManger.instance.playerTankN]

I hope this works.